# Simple paging from Single Array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to do a paging from single array

```
$input = Array
        (
            [0] => 'A',
            [1] => 'B',
            [2] => 'C'
            ...

        )
```

example `$show_per_page=2;`

in page 1

```
paging($input,$page, $show_per_page);

$output = Array(
                [0]=>'A',
                [1]=>'B'
        );
```

in page 2

```
$output = Array(                
                [2]=>'B'
        );
```

I Know about `array_slice` but it is not right for this case.Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I'd use array_chunk: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: `array_chunk` will be inefficient.  `array_slice` will work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `array_slice` is exactly what you want.  It's the most efficient way to do this.  Here's what you need.

```
function get_page(array $input, $pageNum, $perPage) {
    $start = ($pageNum-1) * $perPage;
    $end = $start + $perPage;
    $count = count($input);

    // Conditionally return results
    if ($start < 0 || $count <= $start) {
        // Page is out of range
        return array(); 
    } else if ($count <= $end) {
        // Partially-filled page
        return array_slice($input, $start);
    } else {
        // Full page 
        return array_slice($input, $start, $end - $start);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Steven's answer will work, but the `if/elseif/else` is unnecessary (at least in PHP 5.3 and above--perhaps it was needed in older versions):

```
/**
 * @param array $array Array to be paged
 * @param int $pageNumber One-based pageNumber to return
 * @param int $pageSize Desired page size
 * @return array
 */
public function getPage($array, $pageNumber, $pageSize)
{
    $start = --$pageNumber * $pageSize;
    return array_slice($array, $start, $pageSize);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use --$pageNumber when using a 1-based page numbering. Otherwise you'll start with -1.

Answer (score 0):

try this,,

```
function paging($data, $limit, $page){
        $jmlData = count($data);
        if(!empty($limit)){
            $totalHalaman = ceil($jmlData/$limit);  
        }else{
            $totalHalaman = 1;
        }

        if(!empty($page) && !empty($limit)){
            $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
        }else{
            $start = 0;
        }

        $end = $start + $limit;

        if($start < 0 || $totalHalaman < $page){
            return array();
        } elseif($start == 0 && $limit == 0){
            return array_slice($data, $totalHalaman);
        }else{
            return array_slice($data, $start, $end - $start);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you user PHP 5.x

```
$pages = array_chunk($goodfiles, 5);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => About_RFSB06WEB.flv
        [1] => Kids_Excited.flv
        [2] => Kids_Start_Run.flv
        [3] => Kids_start.jpg
        [4] => Kids_start_sm.jpg
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => image01.jpg
        [1] => image02.jpg
        [2] => image03.jpg
        [3] => image04.jpg
        [4] => image05.jpg        
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => image06.jpg
        [1] => image07.jpg
        [2] => image08.jpg
    )
)
```